# how to read two parameters of the same type?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method to transfer funds from one account to another..

I'm trying to take both sending and receiving account numbers  of account class as input parameters but I'm getting invalid account number exception.

How to do this without generating exceptions?
IS there any way to make both parameters as 'accountNumber'?

```
public int fundTransfer(int accountNumber, int accountNumber1, int amount) throws InvalidAccountNumberException, InsufficientBalanceException{

    Account account=searchaccount(accountNumber);
    Account account1= searchaccount(accountNumber1);

    if(amount>0){
        account.setAmount(account.getAmount()-amount);
        account1.setAmount(account1.getAmount()+amount);
    }else{
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
    }

    throw new InvalidAccountNumberException();
}
```

Comment: Sure you can, it's called [variable arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) (or varargs in short) using the `...` notation. But wouldn't it be more logical to have two separate parameters - `sender` and `recipient`?

Comment: Your code throws the exception unconditionally.

Comment: could you specify which line is the cause of the error?

Comment: a) there is no return statement for your method. b) throwing an InvalidAccountException with no check will throw that exception every time.

Comment: this is statement throw new InvalidAccountNumberException(); is running everytime you call this method because it is outside of the if else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my opinion on the code that you can change:

```
public int fundTransfer(int accountNumber, int accountNumber1, int amount) throws InvalidAccountNumberException, InsufficientBalanceException{

    Account account=searchaccount(accountNumber);
    Account account1= searchaccount(accountNumber1);

    if(amount>0){
        account.setAmount(account.getAmount()-amount);
        account1.setAmount(account1.getAmount()+amount);
    }else{
        throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
    }
}
```

and place the `throw new InvalidAccountNumberException();` inside the `searchaccount` function

Comment: i removed the last throw and added a return statement with accountNumber1's balance and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`throw new InvalidAccountNumberException();` is running every time you call this method because it is outside of the if else statement cluster.

Try this:

```
public int fundTransfer(int accountNumber, int accountNumber1, int amount) throws InvalidAccountNumberException, InsufficientBalanceException{

        Account account=searchaccount(accountNumber);
        Account account1= searchaccount(accountNumber1);

        if(amount>0){
            account.setAmount(account.getAmount()-amount);
            account1.setAmount(account1.getAmount()+amount);
        }else{
            throw new InsufficientBalanceException();
        }

           // throw new InvalidAccountNumberException();
    }
}
```

Comment: throw should be the last statement, you can't add two throw statements, it's a compile error